# Can I use a local database with Stormpath?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, stormpath

I'm working with a web application in Asp.Net Core 1 and would like to integrate authentication, I thought of using `Stormpath` but can not connect to a local database to make the login match.

If there is no way, what choice do I use?
Thank you

Comment: I’m not sure if Stormpath offers this but if you’re willing to switch or look into Auth0, you might find this handy: https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/mysql

Comment: Would give more detail on what you are trying to achieve? Also there is a active user on here, [http://stackoverflow.com/users/3191599/nate-barbettini](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3191599/nate-barbettini) who is the package author and might be another resource for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stormpath will store your user accounts, but you can also use a local database to 'relate' to your Stormpath user accounts.

The idea is pretty simple. When you store a user in Stormpath, you'll get back an account object. This object has an `href` property which is a unique ID for the user.

If you want to create a database table named `books`, that has an `author_id` ForeignKey type field, you would define the `author_id` field as a TEXT field, then store the account `href` from Stormpath there.

This is how you would 'relate' to Stormpath accounts.