# how can use a local database(Mysql) to relate Stormpath user accounts

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, stormpath

i'm developing web application using Spring Boot,Mysql and StormPath for managing user 
i found this Solution 
 [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42362996/can-i-use-a-local-database-with-stormpath?answertab=oldest#tab-top)! 
someone can give me more explication or an example how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Each Stormpath `Account` has a unique ID (called `href`) which looks like this: `https://api.stormpath.com/v1/accounts/3Yrc1TJ2sBFldRtu6nfzf2`.

In your MySQL database you will need to have an ID column where you will store the same ID. That why you will be able to relate the Stormpath Account with the MySQL account.